# Getting powerbi embed token 403 Forbidden

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to get an embed token for power bi embedded.

I'm using 'App owns data' embed scenario.

I first get the access token of Azure AD and use it as Bearer token when calling embed token

Here is my Postman request details:

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groyupid}/dashboards/{dashboardid}/GenerateToken](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7Bgroyupid%7D/dashboards/%7Bdashboardid%7D/GenerateToken)

Request body

`{accessLevel:"View"}`

In authorization section I added the access token.

I received a `403 Forbidden` response.

Here how I get the access token
[image]

[image]

I noticed that there is also another url to get token : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`
What is the difference between the one with tenant id in the url
Then permissions for the AAD PowerBI application
[image]

**Update**

Thanks for the help I get another 404 not found error now

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
        "pbi.error": {
            "code": "PowerBIEntityNotFound",
            "parameters": {},
            "details": [],
            "exceptionCulprit": 1
        }
    }
}
```

For information I have added permission in PBI admin portal to `pbireportingGroup`  an Azure security group that I created. ( as mentionned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers) )
[image]

Then I added to this group the AAD as member

[image]

Is that what should I do ?

Comment: If the answer can't resolve your issue, please share a screenshot about how you get the access token of Azure AD in postman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

403 means that your access token doesn't have the required permissions.

[image]

And you need to add the [master account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/get-azuread-access-token#access-token-with-a-master-account) and [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/get-azuread-access-token#access-token-with-service-principal) as the owner of the group / workspace (it may take 15 minutes to take effect).

**UPDATE:**

Now that you are using client credential flow, you should set application permissions:

[image]

And the `resource` in the request body should be `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/`.

Besides, you need to [add the service principal as the admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-4---add-the-service-principal-to-your-workspace) of this workspace in Azure AD. (enter the name of your Azure AD app, and it will recognize its client id)

Comment: @infodev What is the body of the request?

Comment: @infodev Looks like you are using client_credential flow but the permissions are all delegated which are not supported by this flow.

Comment: @infodev Please share your request body of getting access token and try to add application permissions (not delegated permission) into your Azure AD app.

Comment: I added more details , I dont know the difference between delegated and not delegated permissions

Comment: I changed the ressource url and permissions ( not granted them ) now I get 401 unauthorized response.

Comment: @infodev You should grant admin consent for them.

Comment: @infodev I just updated my answer again. Please pay attention to the last sentence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222237/discussion-between-infodev-and-allen-wu).